# Why ObjectId is empty while passing model to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4

I've just started using MongoDB and i have problem.
While i try to pass object to controller which containts Id (ObjectId), this Id is empty

My View code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

<fieldset>
    <legend>Product</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)


    <input type="submit" value="Save" />

</fieldset>
}
```

Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Product product)
    {         
        _db.Update(product);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Action begins right, i mean, all properties in product are correct but Id (which is mongo's ObjectId) is just empty (Creation date is 1970, rest properties are just zeros)

I dont know what to do...
Please, help.

Comment: could you show your Index action?

Comment: ...and route mappings.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov, but index is fine.
I see on breakpoint, that Id is empty. 
Index action is just `return View()` (no, there is no list of products. list is in other place, but it really doesn't matter).

Comment: in this case, what do you want to get in Id? If you didn't set this value.

Comment: @marceln, but it's almost empty project! every settings are default!

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov, `Id` is set correctly! As you can see input with `id` is hidden but in source i see that value is something like `51a37e962ae6fd2ab40f2fbf`. So everything seems to be OK.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov, Moreover, when i try to do action Edit 

`@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id });` then in URL i see this Id and everything works fine. Problem is while i try to save changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because mvc don't know how to create ObjectId from string. You can create your own model binder like in this article http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/06/12/model-binding-mongodb-objectid-with-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.Net (including Core) MVC the easiest way I found was to use: `new ObjectId(yourString)` ...This will give you a MongoDB ObjectId from a string and should work with any of your queries.